# Installing power for irrigation controller in conduit?

Tags: electrical, nec, irrigation

I have a property where the irrigation controller is mounted on an exterior wall-its power cable is plugged into a wet in use GFCI outlet. Beyond the outlet, the power cable hangs off the wall and is exposed to the elements.

Recently had a home inspector report that the power cable should be permanently installed in conduit.

My prior understanding is that cutting the plug off an appliance and hardwiring it violates electrical code. But I can't locate the exact section that prohibits it. The cable attached to the irrigation controller is 'SJTW' which is not listed in 2020 NEC 310.4(A). But then in 310.10(C)(3) It says cables installed in wet locations can: "Be of a type listed for use in wet locations." This SJTW has "Water Resistant" printed on the jacket.

Not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Is the existing cord the one that came attached to the controller when it came to the factory, or was it field-fitted sometime down the road?

Comment: This cord is permanently attached to the transformer inside the controller enclosure.

Comment: How is said irrigation controller mounted to the wall?

Comment: Plastic enclosure is fastened to exterior with two screws.

Comment: Is the inspector saying the controller should be wired directly to home wiring through a conduit, rather than via an outlet, as if its inlet box was part of the house wiring?  So that irrigation controllers in general may not use plugs if installed outside?  Citation for that, if so?  Or is inspector saying the actual power cable should be in a conduit, in which case how is the conduit supposed to interface to the outlet box?

Comment: @jay613 I suspect the inspector is expecting to have the NEMA 5-15P plug cut off the controller power cable then duct the remaining cord through a PVC raceway run into the GFCI junction box. Then connect the cord on the load side on rear of GFCI.

Comment: At least that is my assumption. Like you said, how would one interface conduit to the front of an outlet. Not to mention, the plug wouldn't fit through 1/2 or 3/4 inch PVC.

Comment: Your plug and socket is probably ok,  hard wiring through conduit using proper wiring in  the conduit is probably ok, but using the widget manufacturer's power cable in a conduit to the terminals on the back of an outlet is almost certainly not ok.  I'm not a pro, but I think I've picked up at least that much in these forums.